# How to write a query to upadate the two or more table record

Tags: c#, .net

I want to update two table records.

```
    UPDATE Users as TBL1, UserEmailAddresses as TBL2 SET  TBL1.GivenName=ABC, 
    TBL1.Surname =Elatrache, TBL1.Gender= M, TBL1.BirthDate = 1948-04-06, TBL2.Address
    = abc@yahoo.com, WHERE Uers.ExternalId=2022880-01 AND Users.UserOID=User
    EmailAddresses.UserOID
```

Comment: This is clearly not real code first of all. Second, just use two update statements. You are wasting energy creating a problem so you can find a solution. This assumes MSSQL; if using MySQL it is actually possible to do this.

Comment: I am not able to execute this query. I want to update the two tables , I am using SQL server 2008

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @david, you need to use two update statements and wrap them in a transaction.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE Users SET
    GivenName='ABC', 
    Surname ='Elatrache',
    Gender= 'M',
    BirthDate = '1948-04-06'
WHERE ExternalId=2022880-01 
    AND UserOID = 'User'

UPDATE UserEmailAddresses SET Address = 'abc@yahoo.com'
    WHERE <something depending on your relationships between users and useremail addresses>

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```